# Python string format function gives unexpected results when specifying precision

Tags: python, string, format, precision

When I do any of these I get the expected results as shown:

```
>>> '{text:{fill}{align}{width}}'.format(text = 'abcdef', width = 8, fill = '~', align = '^')
'~abcdef~'
>>> '{0:~^8}'.format('abcdef')
'~abcdef~'
>>> '{0:~^8.4}'.format('abcdef')
'~~abcd~~'
>>> '{num:{fill}{align}{width}{type}}'.format(num = 12.34, width = 12, fill = '~', align = '^', type = 'f')
'~12.340000~~'
>>> '{0:~^12.4f}'.format(12.34)
'~~12.3400~~~'
```

However, when I specify precision dynamically, I get much wider output than expected:

```
>>> '{text:{fill}{align}{width}{precision}}'.format(text = 'abcdef', width = 8, fill = '~', align = '^', precision = .4)
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~abcd~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~'
>>> '{num:{fill}{align}{width}{precision}{type}}'.format(num = 12.34, width = 12, fill = '~', align = '^', type = 'f', precision = .4) 
'~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~12.3400~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~'
```

Am I doing something wrong or have the wrong expectations or is there a bug?

I'm using Python 2.7.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the dot in the format string instead of using a decimal value in the assignment to `precision`.

```
>>> '{text:{fill}{align}{width}.{precision}}'.format(text = 'abcdef', width=8, fill = '~', align = '^', precision = 4)
'~~abcd~~'
>>> '{num:{fill}{align}{width}.{precision}{type}}'.format(num = 12.34, width=12, fill = '~', align = '^', type = 'f', precision = 4)
'~~12.3400~~~'
```

Otherwise, without the dot, `width` and the string representation of `precision` (.4 becomes '0.4') get concatenated as strings and the integer portion of the result is used as the width. So, in one of your examples where width is 8 and precision is .4, the resulting width becomes 80 (from truncating 80.4).